# Java Swing, Mysql error from PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, sqlexception

This is my table on mysql:
[image]

This is my Java code:

```
                public static final String  username  = "root";
public static final String  password  = "sundayman";
public static final String  connect  = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lives";
Connection sqlConn = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
                try {

                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                sqlConn = DriverManager.getConnection(connect, username, password);

                pst = (PreparedStatement)sqlConn.prepareStatement("insert into lives_table(Name,Latin Name,Live's Class,Cell Structure,Nutrition,Respiratory,Move,Reproductive)"+"values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

                pst.setString(1, l.getName());
                pst.setString(2, l.getLatin());
                pst.setString(3, l.getLive_class());
                pst.setString(4, l.getCell_type());
                pst.setString(5, l.getFeed());
                pst.setString(6, l.getO2());
                pst.setString(7, l.getMove());
                pst.setString(8, l.getReproductive());
               
                pst.executeUpdate();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Live Recorded!");
                

                

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Register.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Register.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
    }
```

I got this Error:
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

What's wrong?

Comment: Why are you trying to concatenate two separate strings for your SQL statement? I would guess the issue is that you didn't leave any spaces before the values keyword so you a syntax error. Make your string a single string to reduce the chance an making a mistake like this. Also what does a JFrame have to do with an SQLException. Only include relevant information when asking a question.

Comment: You can't possibly have column names, not only with spaces in them but singles quotes too!

Comment: @g00se Not true because there they are in the screenshot!  :)  One shouldn't have column names with those characters but one must learn the rules first.  To me this seems like a reasonable mistake for someone familiar with spreadsheets to make while learning about databases.

Comment: @Paul Wow you're right! Sorry all [but don't ;) ]

Comment: @camickr You and I know the `JFrame` is not related to the exception but someone learning Java, Swing, and relational databases _at the same time_ may not know what is relevant and what is not. New users who are learning new skills and technologies often don't provide enough detail when asking a question.  In this, the opposite case, I don't think OP posted an onerous amount of extraneous detail. Please be gentle in your corrections and try to remember what it was like to not know things. :) I frequently learn new (not code-related) skills; sometimes it's hard to know even what to ask.

Comment: @g00se We are in 100% agreement on that!  :D

Comment: Mr.camickr Next time I will be caref pay attention ,thanks. Thanks everyone, especially l @Paul  you are so kind :)

Comment: @Pault, I was gentle. I made a simple point. If you get an SQLException then the error is likely with the SQL statement so that is where you concentrate your problem solving effort. Worrying about a JFrame will get you off track both for yourself or anybody else reading the question. Part of programming is learning how to isolate the error so you can concentrate on a solution. A valuable programming lesson.

Comment: *but someone learning Java, Swing, and relational databases at the same time may not know what is relevant and what is not.* - another good tip. Don't try to learn 3 concepts at the same time. Learn each concept separately. Once each step works separately then you add them together. So maybe first learn how to display a JFrame with a few components. Then learn how to do an SQL query. Then you add the SQL to the Swing app. Test smaller piece of code separately before adding them to your main app. This makes it easier to debug. If something stops working you know what you last changed.

Comment: @camickr You are right, I confuse it. Sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need column names to have special characters, you must delimit them in back-ticks:

WRONG:

```
insert into lives_table(Name,Latin Name,Live's Class,Cell Structure,Nutrition,Respiratory,Move,Reproductive)...
```

RIGHT:

```
insert into lives_table(Name,`Latin Name`,`Live's Class`,`Cell Structure`,Nutrition,Respiratory,Move,Reproductive)...
```

Most people decide it is simpler to avoid using whitespace and punctuation characters in their column names.